# C# DLL remove Interop and AxInterop files

Tags: c#, dll, com, interop

I'm developing a DLL in C# that uses external C++ DLL COM-Components in the GUI and also for the code side. In total I am using 3 other components and for each one I reference I get a "Interop.ComponentName.dll" file included in the output.

I did try to change the setting "Copy Local" in the "Properties" window to false but I get errors at runtime that the main DLL cannot find the files.

I understand that these are needed for the program to function but is it possible to use these files in a subdirectory such as the main dll is in ""../extras/Test.dll" and I would like the Interop files in "../extras/TestResources/"?

Extra Info: I'm using C# with Visual Studio 2008 in Windows XP SP3.

Thanks, K.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which interop DLLs are you referencing? If they're non-standard (i.e. not included in your targeted .NET framework distribution), then Visual Studio may include them in your project output as they're not registered in your Global Assembly Cache.

Consider how your distributed C# application would reference external DLLs.  If they're part of the .NET distribution, then they're properly registered in the user's GAC.  Otherwise, your setup/deployment project would register them.  If it's the latter, then if you go to your original project's properties, under Build, you should see the output path field. Visual Studio's internal build utility will only allow you to output your project's build files to a single directory.

However, there IS a way to achieve what you're asking.  It's quite a bit more complicated than allowing Visual Studio to handle your deployment though.  Take a look into MSBuild.exe and build scripts.

Comment: They are non-standard, a couple I have made and a couple (for the GUI) are built by others and I do not have access to rebuilding.  Basically the DLL files I am using are in the same directory or parent directory. I'll keep looking into it thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To enable the CLR to find assemblies that are not in your bin folder or the other locations it automatically searches, you can use the <codeBase> element in your app.config file.

See [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb(vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb%28vs.71%29.aspx) for details on how to do this.

2 lines for you to note from the linked article:

- If the assembly is a private assembly, the codebase setting must be a path relative to the application's directory.
- For assemblies without a strong name, version is ignored and the loader uses the first appearance of <codebase> inside <dependentAssembly>